# 1. How to avoid Red Cross in DatagridView C#.net windows form?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a gridview which updates values periodically as well as automatically(based on autorefresh timer)
My Problem is that I get a Big Red Cross over my gridview.

http://koenaerts.ca/wp-content/uploads/dgvredx.png

Answer (score 0):

if (gridView.InvokeRequired)
gridView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => gridView.DataSource =YOUR_DATASOURCE));
else
gridView.DataSource = YOUR_DATASOURCE;